# Dropdown opening issue inside of ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-grid

I get a new row on dropdown Click and am using  `enableCellEditOnFocus` and when I try to open the dropdown it is not opening and alternate dropdowns are working properly. To avoid confusion I altered the code and I am showing that bit of code that is giving me the error and here is [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GBUvMO9seMq2reggDfzW?p=preview).

This is my ui-grid object

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
enableCellEditOnFocus: true 
};
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
{ name: 'gender', displayName: 'Gender', editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', width: '20%', 
   editDropdownValueLabel: 'gender', editDropdownOptionsArray: [
  { id: 1, gender: 'male' }, 
  { id: 2, gender: 'female' } 
] }  ];
```

I add new row by using this code:

```
$scope.addNewRow = function () {
    $scope.gridOptions.data.push({
    "gender": "male"});
};
//adding new row inside of uigrid
$scope.newRow = function (row, columnIndex) {
    tempIndexSave = "";
    tempIndexSave = _.indexOf($scope.gridOptions.data, row);
    var length = $scope.gridOptions.data.length;
    if (length - 1 == tempIndexSave) {
        $scope.addNewRow();
    }
};
```

Comment: The functionality you are trying to achieve is not straight forward. You want to add a new row when user starts editing an existing row? If yes, then why you want this functionality? Why can't you separate the adding new row part from editing? May be you can have a button to add a new row...

Comment: @GaneshKumar actual that is clients requirement, he wants that and below that grid i have one save button that saves all the data of grid

Comment: So every time user clicks on the drop down, you want to add a new row?

Comment: Yes i want a new row and i am getting a new row but dropdown is not working in that, you can see my plunker above

Comment: One possible cause of this is that adding a new row may be interfering with the editing functionality. Because, if I add a new row through a button outside the grid, the drop down appears properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to [these lines](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/9d1a0b46e54983e09e0be8f89f9fac0ee74046e4/src/features/cellnav/js/cellnav.js#L1053-L1068) where you can see there's a hack for screen readers.

This hack may bring issues similar to yours because it depends on `beginCellEdit` and `afterCellEdit` events to be fired evenly and with a fixed pattern:

- `beginCellEdit`
- `afterCellEdit`
- `beginCellEdit`
- `afterCellEdit`
- `beginCellEdit`

...

Adding a new row while already editing a row breaks this pattern since, for the new created row, you are missing a `beginCellEdit`, so the preventMouseDown function will always fire, preventing user interaction.

I put up a workaround, but I don't advise you using this if you want to keep compatibility with screen readers (see comments before the lines in the file I linked to), because the workaround might break the hack.

The workaround consists of raising a fake `beginCellEdit` while adding the row, as you can see in [this updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LyfW6YhTuc0MBXX4YZfw?p=preview).

```
...
if (length - 1 == tempIndexSave) {
  $scope.addNewRow();
  $scope.gridApi.edit.raise.beginCellEdit();
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks mate...this is wat i wanted :)